# SQL Server query scanning more partitions than expected

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

So my team has the following select statement in one of our stored procedures

```
SELECT
    ai.Name
    ,dc.Component 
    ,SUM(dc.Value) Value
FROM 
    Warm.DailyCosts dc
    JOIN Warm.AccountInfo ai
        ON dc.AccountInfoId = ai.Id
WHERE
    ai.CorrelationId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    AND ((dc.CalendarId >= (20190601 + ai.DayOfMonth - 1)
        AND dc.CalendarId < 20190701)
    OR (dc.CalendarId >= 20270601
        AND dc.CalendarId < (20270601 + ai.DayOfMonth - 1)))
GROUP BY        
    Name
    ,Component
```

And we've partitioned the DailyCosts table on the months of each year as follows:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_CostDateByYearMonth](int) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
    20180101,
    20180201,
    20180301,
    20180401,
    20180501,
    20180601,
    20180701,
    20180801,
    20180901,
    20181001,
    20181101,
    20181201,

    ...

    20300101,
    20300201,
    20300301,
    20300401,
    20300501,
    20300601,
    20300701,
    20300801,
    20300901,
    20301001,
    20301101,
    20301201)
```

We noticed that when we ran the procedure, rather than finding the appropriate partitions right away it looked like it was scanning partitions from either end. For the above example, it viewed partitions `20180101` up to `20190701` and `20301201` down to `20270601` totaling 62 partitions.

When we removed the math from the where statement (`+ ai.DayOfMonth - 1`), the partitions read dropped down to 2, `20190601` and `20270601`, as expected. Note that we use seed data and `DayOfMonth` is set to 15 on every account.

What causes the server to scan the partitions when this math is included, and is it actually looking through all of the indexes in these partitions or is it just checking their ranges and moving on?

Any and all sources you can provide would go a long way in helping us understand!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Reasoning

When comparing the column of the non partitioned table against the partitioned table, sql server will not be able to know what `DayOfMonth` will hold, even if all of them are 15.

As a result it would not know which partitions to return to satisfy this filtering when joining the two tables.

A different example to give some more insight can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/partition-key-questions-in-sql-server-2008/24847).

---

### Testing

I was able to recreate your issue, for further questions please add as much information as possible. 
*This could be Table definition, indexes, partition scheme, ...*

*The DDL & DML is at the bottom.*

When running the query we can get the same result:

[image]

*62 partitions returned.*

On the seek predicates it tries to filter what it can, this is the two filters on `CalendarId` that do not have the  `+ DayOfMonth-1`.

[image]

This translates to

```
WHERE ...
    AND (( dc.CalendarId < 20190701)
    OR (dc.CalendarId >= 20270601))
...
```

When running the query with these filters you will see the same amount of rows returned on accessing the table in the query plan.

Only after getting this data, it can and will be joined to the `AccountInfo` table on the `ID`'s and the `DayOfMonth - 1`

[image]

[image]

To confirm your statement that when we remove the column that only two partitions are scanned:

```
SELECT
    ai.Name
    ,SUM(dc.Component )
    ,SUM(dc.Value) Value
FROM 
    Warm.DailyCosts dc
    JOIN Warm.AccountInfo ai
        ON dc.AccountInfoId = ai.Id
WHERE
    ai.CorrelationId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    AND ((dc.CalendarId >= (20190601  - 1)
        AND dc.CalendarId < 20190701)
    OR (dc.CalendarId >= 20270601
        AND dc.CalendarId < (20270601  - 1)))
GROUP BY            Name
```

Only two are accessed and used:

[image: a]

---

### Solution

I am going to **assume** that `DayOfMonth` only goes up to `31` days.

If you know these boundaries, you can 'hard code' them so that sql server knows what partitions to look for. After this you can add the extra filtering.

E.G.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    ai.Name
    ,dc.Component 
    ,dc.Value 
    ,dc.CalendarId
    ,ai.DayOfMonth
FROM 
    Warm.DailyCosts dc
    JOIN Warm.AccountInfo ai
        ON dc.AccountInfoId = ai.Id
WHERE
    ai.CorrelationId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    AND ((dc.CalendarId >= (20190601 )
        AND dc.CalendarId < 20190701)
    OR (dc.CalendarId >= 20270601
        AND dc.CalendarId < (20270701)))

)

SELECT Name,Component,SUM(Value)
FROM CTE 
WHERE ((CalendarId >= (20190601 + DayOfMonth - 1)
        AND CalendarId < 20190701)
    OR (CalendarId >= 20270601
        AND CalendarId < (20270601 + DayOfMonth - 1)))

GROUP BY        
    Name
    ,Component
```

The sole purpose of the  `cte` is to let sql server know that it can also filter on `dc.CalendarId >= dc.CalendarId >= (20190601 ) OR dc.CalendarId < (20270701))`.

*Sidenote: Adding a constraint does not work to enforce this.*

**This query gives us the result we want, with the correct  partition elemination:**

[image]

[image]

Only accessing partitions `19` & `21`.

You can probably also use `OR` / `AND` logic to get the same result if you prefer. The important part is getting the boundaries known.

---

### Test data

```
CREATE SCHEMA WARM
GO

CREATE TABLE Warm.DailyCosts(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                            Component int, 
                             Value int, 
                             CalendarId INT, 
                             AccountInfoId int
                             )


CREATE TABLE Warm.AccountInfo(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                              Name VARCHAR(25),
                              CorrelationId uniqueidentifier,
                              DayOfMonth int
                              );
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] ADD FILEGROUP [Partitionfg]
GO
USE [test]
GO
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_CostDateByYearMonth](int) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
    20180101,
    20180201,
    20180301,
    20180401,
    20180501,
    20180601,
    20180701,
    20180801,
    20180901,
    20181001,
    20181101,
    20181201,
    20190101,
    20190201,
    20190301,
    20190401,
    20190501,
    20190601,
    20190701,
    20270601,
    20270701,
    20270801,
    20270901,
    20271001,
    20271101,
    20271201,
    20280101,
    20280201,
    20280301,
    20280401,
    20280501,
    20280601,
    20280701,
    20280801,
    20280901,
    20281001,
    20281101,
    20281201,
    20290101,
    20290201,
    20290301,
    20290401,
    20290501,
    20290601,
    20290701,
    20290801,
    20290901,
    20291001,
    20291101,
    20291201,
    20300101,
    20300201,
    20300301,
    20300401,
    20300501,
    20300601,
    20300701,
    20300801,
    20300901,
    20301001,
    20301101,
    20301201)


CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_CostDateByYearMonth]  
AS PARTITION [PF_CostDateByYearMonth]  
ALL TO ( [Partitionfg] );  

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ptci ON  Warm.DailyCosts(CalendarId,Id) ON [PS_CostDateByYearMonth](CalendarId) ;
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [test] ADD FILE ( NAME = N'TestPartition', FILENAME = N'D:\DATA\TestPartition.ndf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB ) TO FILEGROUP [Partitionfg]
GO
USE [test]
GO

INSERT INTO  Warm.DailyCosts(Component, 
                             Value, 
                             CalendarId, 
                             AccountInfoId 
                             )
SELECT TOP(1000000) --1M
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        20180101 +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 1000 % 1000 ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2 
-- 2018
INSERT INTO  Warm.DailyCosts(Component, 
                             Value, 
                             CalendarId, 
                             AccountInfoId 
                             )
SELECT TOP(1000000) --1M
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        20190101 +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 1000 % 1000 ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2 
-- 2019
INSERT INTO  Warm.DailyCosts(Component, 
                             Value, 
                             CalendarId, 
                             AccountInfoId 
                             )

SELECT TOP(1000000) --1M
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        20280101 +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) / 1000 % 1000 ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2 
-- 2028

INSERT INTO Warm.AccountInfo(
                              Name ,
                              CorrelationId,
                              DayOfMonth 
                              )

SELECT TOP(3000000) --3M
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(10)) + 'a',
       '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
       15
FROM master..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY master..spt_values spt2 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Component_Value_DailyCosts] ON Warm.DailyCosts
 (Component,Value) 
ON [PS_CostDateByYearMonth](CalendarId);
GO
```